# How to diff a single directory in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff, dvcs

I have two local mercurial repos, let's call them product and skunkworks.  Skunkworks is a clone of product and has a lot of recent commit activity against it.  I need to be able to package up the diffs from one small part of the directory tree and pull those out as a patch file.

I've got the following layout on disk:

```
c:/dev/product
c:/dev/skunkworks
```

The area of diffs I want to package up is from c:/dev/skunkworks/buildstuff.  This directory exists in the product repo.  I don't want to expose everyone else to the changes in the rest of skunkworks just yet, but need to be able to share my new build goodness.

I've tried a number of different parameter settings and combinations of the 'hg diff' command but am obviously doing something wrong.  Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily, but first lemme suggest that the next time you're doing to independent bits of work (the build work and the rest of skunkworks) you do them in separate heads -- then you can push the buildwork directly to product using hg push w/o moving skunkworks over there too.  That pattern would look like:

```
hg clone product skunkworks
cd skunkworks
... build hacking ...
hg commit
... build hacking ...
hg commit
hg update REVNUMBER # where revnumber is the last revision that exists in product
... skunkworks hacking ...
hg commit  # at this point you'll see (+1 heads)
... more skunkworks hacking ...
hg commit
```

at that point your skunkworks clone will have two heads, one with build work and one with skunkworks.  You can switch back and forth while working, alternating between build and sunkworks while keeping them separate within the same clone.  If while working on skunkworks you want the build niceties too you can do:

```
hg update SKUNKWORKSHEAD
hg merge BUILDHEAD
```

that merges the buildwork into skunkworks, but the buildwork stuff still doesn't have any skunkworks as its parent, so at anytime you could do:

```
cd ../product
hg pull -r BUILDHEAD ../skunkworks
```

and you'd move only the build stuff into product without any of the other skunkworks changes.

This is the optimal way to do such a thing (technically called anonymous branches) because when you **are** ready to move skunkworks into product it'll know exactly where the build changes came from and how to correctly integrate them into skunkworks.

Whew, all that said what you want to do now is probably:

```
cd skunkworks
hg diff -I buildstuff/** -r LAST_REV_IN_PRODUCT -r tip > ../applyme.patch
cd ../product
hg import --no-commit ../applyme.patch
hg commit
```

The drawback there is that when you do merge skunkworks back into product all the build changes will already be there, which will make the merge less automatic that it might otherwise be.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for taking the time to explain the anonymous branch approach.  I'm coming from SVN so I'm still trying to wrap my head around clones and the different 'branching' options in mercurial.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want is to run in skunkworks `hg diff buildstuff -r <rev>` where `<rev>` is the last revision matching the product repo.

Below creates a number of files and directories representing the original repository:

```
C:\>hg init test
C:\>cd test
C:\test>echo >file1
C:\test>echo >file2
C:\test>md dir1
C:\test>md dir2
C:\test>echo >dir1\file3
C:\test>echo >dir1\file4
C:\test>echo >dir2\file5
C:\test>echo >dir2\file6
C:\test>hg ci -Am 1
adding dir1/file3
adding dir1/file4
adding dir2/file5
adding dir2/file6
adding file1
adding file2
```

We'll clone and change a file in each of the subdirectories:

```
C:\test>cd ..
C:\>hg clone test skunk
updating to branch default
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\>cd skunk
C:\skunk>echo >>dir1\file4
C:\skunk>echo >>dir2\file5
C:\skunk>hg st
M dir1\file4
M dir2\file5

C:\skunk>hg ci -m skunk
```

Now just display the diff for dir2 compared to the previous checkin:

```
C:\skunk>hg diff dir2 -r 0
diff --git a/dir2/file5 b/dir2/file5
--- a/dir2/file5
+++ b/dir2/file5
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 ECHO is on.
+ECHO is on.
```